# Как сделать так, чтобы telegram bot работал с несколькими пользователями?(java)

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegram

Написал telegram бота, он должен выводить для разных пользователей разную информацию. При работе с ним с разных аккаунтов, он работает так, как будто с ним работает один пользователь. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить.
Вот часть кода:

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

 if(message != null && message.hasText()){

        if(message.getText().equals("/start")){
            sendMsg(message, area.toString());
            flag = true;
            flagTwo = true;

        }
        result = message.getText();

        if (message.getText().equals(eq()) && flag) {
            GetAutorization  get = new GetAutorization();
            String mes = message.getText();
            prefs.put("pid", mes);
            get.getArea();
            parseGet = new JParseGetAuthorization();
            parseGet.jParse(get.getResponse());
            ArrayList<School> school = parseGet.getSchool();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < school.size(); i++){
                School schools = school.get(i);
                builder.append(schools.getId()).append(": ").append(schools.getName()).append("\n");
            }

            sendMsg(message,builder.toString());
            flag = false;
        }

        if(message.getText().equals(eq(parseGet)) && flagTwo){
            GetAutorization  get = new GetAutorization();
            String mes = message.getText();
            prefs.put("cn", mes);
            get.getCity();
            parseGet = new JParseGetAuthorization();
            parseGet.jParse(get.getResponse());
            ArrayList<School> school = parseGet.getSchool();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < school.size(); i++){
                School schools = school.get(i);
                builder.append(schools.getId()).append(": ").append(schools.getName()).append("\n");
            }

            sendMsg(message,builder.toString());
            flagTwo =false;
        }
private void sendMsg(Message message, String str) {

    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
    sendMessage.setText(str);
    try{
        execute(sendMessage);
    }catch (TelegramApiException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: А как в принципе здесь различаются пользователи с разных аккаунтов?

Comment: что конкретно он должен выводить?

Comment: @michael_best Бот авторизуется на стороннем сайте и показывает с него информацию

Comment: @Mark здесь очевидно ни как и вот я хотел бы узнать как это реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если проблема в том чтобы различать собеседников, то в коде есть одно место, где это уже реализовано. В самом конце:

```
sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
```

Во входящем сообщении есть поле `ChatId`. Оно указывает от кого пришло сообщение и используется чтобы отправить ответ нужному адресату. Ничто не мешает вынуть `ChatId` сразу по получению сообщения и генерировать ответ с его учетом. Ради интереса просто выведите в консоль не `getText` к примеру, а все сообщение целиком. Там куча информации.

Comment: Да это именно, то что я хотел. Спасибо большое! Если не трудно поясните, пожалуйста. Вот я получу id пользователя, который отправил сообщение, есть какой-нибудь пример как сравнивать эти id, чтобы отделить пользователей? Может условие какое-нибудь

Comment: Напишите класс генератора сообщений. Для каждого пользователя создавайте свой экземпляр этого класса. Тогда у вас будет не один бот на всех, а у каждого собеседника свой собственный.

Comment: Понял, спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Примером такого класса поделитесь?